# Windows programs to create timeline charts?

Tags: windows-xp, charts, timeline

I would like to create a chart for my source control depicting the trunk and all the branches, with various details, like creation date, merge date, created revision, merge revision, close revision etc.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have looked into an appliation called SmartDraw, but unable to the required kind of output from it.

It would be awesome if the data can be generated by reading an Excel file input.

It would be required that the software runs on Windows XP SP3.

Comment: what source control do you use?

Comment: SVN, with Subclipse plugin in Eclipse, but the structure of my repository is messed up and i cant change that, so i need to create this diagram from the data form an excel, so I cant use the 'Revision Graph' functionality from SVN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your data is already in Excel, I'd just use that to chart your data.  You can "fake" a timeline by using an XY chart, with each "branch" sharing the same Y value (so they're all level) and the X values are driven by your date/time fields.  Create a single dummy series for your X axis spacing and labels and label your data points based upon your series names, or other values (I use XY Chart Labeler, free add-in from Rob Bovey) you mentioned.

It's not quite as pretty as your example, but it keeps the data in Excel, doesn't require additional software, and by using some dynamic named ranges, your chart can update as your Excel data grows, keeping your chart up-to-date.[image: Excel Timeline]

Also, if you add an additional data series formatted as a bar chart, you can use some banding to show general groupings of various "families" of revisions.  I added a sample in the second image.[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand how to create this. Could you help me understand a little better, I asked about it [here](http://superuser.com/questions/562366/sample-data-to-create-excel-timeline)

Comment: Nice approach. You should consider posting the example document as a reference.